# Removing earlier dates in a month from a range of data points

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using Microsoft excel 2010 on Windows XP.

```
## A ##        ## B ##
1/01/2011         10
5/03/2011         20
30/03/2011        30
4/04/2011         40 
10/05/2011        10 
28/05/2011        30
```

I need to remove duplicate data if it appears twice in a single month, and only keep the later dated data to get the following

```
1/01/2011         10
30/03/2011        30
4/04/2011         40
28/05/2011        30
```

It's okay if I can just clear the contents of the date in the cell that I want to be removed without removing the data.

Can someone please help me on this? I have tried googling and was unable to find a solution. Appreciate all the help I can get, thank you!

Edit: Sorry for missing this out, I need this to be done automatically through a vba code daily over a range of dates and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll create a new column, convert the date to month, using TEXT(xxx,"MMM-YYYY")

Then sort the Date column By Newest to Oldest

Then apply Remove Duplicate, but only select Month (uncheck Date & Value)

Because Remove Duplicate always only retain the first record.

As below

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. However, this does not work if I have dates spanning from 2011-2016 as I will have duplicate months in different years as well. Apologies for not stating my question clearly earlier on.

Comment: Change Month() to TEXT(XX,"MMM-YYYY"), should be fixed